# Using GROUP BY, ORDER BY, GROUP_CONCAT to get oldest rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to use the below statement to get a list of messages for the logged in user. The issue is dispite using group and order by it doesnt always show the most recent message. Can anyone shed some light on this? Should I be using a subquery?

```sql
SELECT 
  messages.message_id,
  messages.message_parent_id,
  messages.message_project_id,
  messages.message_from_id,
  messages.message_from_email,
  messages.message_subject,
  messages.message_body,
  messages.message_sent_datetime,
  CONCAT(
    u_from.forename,
    ' ',
    u_from.surname
  ) AS from_x,
  GROUP_CONCAT(
    CONCAT(
      u_to.user_id,
      '||',
      u_to.forename,
      ' ',
      u_to.surname
    )
  ) AS to_x,
  m_recipients.recipient_message_read 
FROM
  messages 
  INNER JOIN users AS u_from 
    ON messages.message_from_id = u_from.user_id 
  INNER JOIN message_recipients AS m_recipients 
    ON messages.message_id = m_recipients.recipient_message_id 
  INNER JOIN users AS u_to 
    ON m_recipients.recipient_user_id = u_to.user_id 
WHERE (
    m_recipients.recipient_user_id = '$current_user_id' 
    OR messages.message_from_id = '$current_user_id'
  ) 
  AND messages.message_project_id = '$project_id' 
GROUP BY messages.message_parent_id 
ORDER BY messages.message_sent_datetime DESC
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7fbfa/3

Comment: What happens when you add `..ORDER BY messages.message_sent_datetime DESC  LIMIT 1`

Comment: While this works, it limits my results to 1

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you don't need?

`GROUP BY messages.message_parent_id,  messages.message_id`

if you are sure than replace `messages.message_sent_datetime` to

```
MAX(messages.message_sent_datetime) as message_sent_datetime,
...
ORDER BY message_sent_datetime
```

or

```
MIN(messages.message_sent_datetime) as message_sent_datetime,
...
ORDER BY message_sent_datetime
```

Ok try [this way](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5243d/5):

```
SELECT 
  messages.message_id,
  messages.message_parent_id,
  messages.message_project_id,
  messages.message_from_id,
  messages.message_from_email,
  messages.message_subject,
  messages.message_body,
  MAX(messages.message_sent_datetime) AS message_sent_datetime,
  messages.message_important,
  u_from.from_x,
  GROUP_CONCAT(u_to.to_x),
  m_recipients.recipient_message_read 
FROM
  messages 
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
      user_id,
      CONCAT(forename,' ',surname) AS from_x
    FROM users 
    ) AS u_from 
    ON messages.message_from_id = u_from.user_id 
  INNER JOIN message_recipients AS m_recipients 
    ON messages.message_id = m_recipients.recipient_message_id 
  INNER JOIN 
     (SELECT
        user_id,
        CONCAT(user_id,'||',forename,' ',surname) AS to_x
      FROM users 
     ) AS u_to 
    ON m_recipients.recipient_user_id = u_to.user_id 
WHERE (
    m_recipients.recipient_user_id = 1
    OR messages.message_from_id = 1
  ) 
  AND messages.message_project_id = 1
GROUP BY messages.message_parent_id
ORDER BY messages.message_sent_datetime DESC
```

Comment: Sorry I tried both solutions and neither got what I wanted. I feel GROUP_CONCAT is causing problems

Comment: could you provide samples of source data and expected result?

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for your help, here is a fiddle, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7fbfa/3  I'm expecting to see the last message sent which says 'hows things?' however this is a essentially an inbox so in a real world scenario there will be more than one result, but i always want to see the newest message for preview purposes. thanks

Comment: while this orders it properly i get 8 results as apposed to 1 per message thead

Comment: fiddle you provided, include just 1 record as result, but we need more to see if order works fine

Comment: hi alex, this is what I'm hoping to see expect it should be displaying this message because it has the newest timestamp - thanks ('16390173-a892-410b-a0ed-cd244819bd2b', 'a4a562b3-4a9d-4870-9cec-dda31ff4027a', 1, 6, '', 'test', 0, 'hows things?', '2015-03-24 15:58:54'),

Comment: @amof check update. as I said before use 'MAX' then http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5243d/5

Comment: Just realised it shows the date is right (15:58:54) but the message corresponding should be 'hows things'?

Answer (score 0):

So eventually I figured this out

```
SELECT

messages.message_id,
messages.message_parent_id,
messages.message_project_id,
messages.message_from_id,
messages.message_from_email,
messages.message_subject,
messages.message_body,
messages.message_sent_datetime, 
messages.message_important,

CONCAT(u_from.forename, ' ', u_from.surname) as from_x,
GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(u_to.forename, ' ', u_to.surname)) as to_x, 

m_recipients.recipient_message_read

FROM (select * from messages WHERE message_project_id = 1 ORDER BY message_sent_datetime desc) messages

INNER JOIN users AS u_from 
    ON messages.message_from_id = u_from.user_id 
INNER JOIN message_recipients AS m_recipients 
    ON messages.message_id = m_recipients.recipient_message_id 
INNER JOIN users AS u_to 
    ON m_recipients.recipient_user_id = u_to.user_id  

WHERE ( m_recipients.recipient_user_id = 1 OR messages.message_from_id = 1 ) 

GROUP BY message_parent_id
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/12a2d/3